# How to display function output as a list, [a], instead of a string, show [a], in context of the example code below

Tags: haskell

I am starting to learn some programming and I have been given the following exercise:

*"Create a function named divisors that takes an integer n > 1 and returns an array with all of the integer's divisors(except for 1 and the number itself), from smallest to largest. If the number is prime return the string '(integer) is prime'.
**Hint: Use divisors :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> Either String [a]**"*

I do not yet understand how to employ the Either type, so in the interim I have decided to begin tackling the problem in baby steps.

Since part of the exercise requires constructing a function to distinguish between prime numbers and non-prime numbers, I decided to first create a provisional function: if the number (a) is not prime, I must display the list of its divisors [1..a]. If the number (a) is prime, I must display the string "(a) is prime".

The following code works:

```hs
divisors a = if length [i | i <- [1..a], mod a i == 0 ] > 2
             then show [i | i <- [1..a], mod a i == 0 ]
             else show a ++ " is prime"
```

Some output of this function is:

```hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( program.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> divisors 1
"1 is prime"
*Main> divisors 2
"2 is prime"
*Main> divisors 3
"3 is prime"
*Main> divisors 4
"[1,2,4]"
*Main> divisors 5
"5 is prime"
*Main> divisors 6
"[1,2,3,6]"
*Main> divisors 7
"7 is prime"
```

However, I do need to display the list as a list [1..a] and not a string "[1..a]". I thus erased (show) from the (then) statement:

```hs
divisors a = if length [i | i <- [1..a], mod a i == 0 ] > 2
             then [i | i <- [1..a], mod a i == 0 ]
             else show a ++ " is prime"
```

but this throws up an error:

```hs
program.hs:11:42: error:
    * No instance for (Integral Char) arising from a use of `mod'
    * In the first argument of `(==)', namely `mod a i'
      In the expression: mod a i == 0
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: mod a i == 0
   |
11 | divisors a = if length [i | i <- [1..a], mod a i == 0 ] > 2
   |                                          ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I do not understand exactly what went wrong and need someone to explain how to display the output of non-prime numbers as a list instead of a string representation of the list.

I do not mind if someone wants to explain how to answer the original exercise question employing the Either type in the solution, if they are willing to explain how to re-formulate my function to employ the Either type properly.

EDIT:
After reading some responses, I attempted the following:

```hs
divisors :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> Either String [a]
divisors a = if length [i | i <- [2..a], mod a i == 0] > 1
             then Right [i | i <- [2..a-1], mod a i == 0]
             else Left (show a ++ " is prime")
```

and it seems to be working!

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Well you've discovered why you need `Either`. Haskell has a strong static type system, and a function needs to return values of a specific type. It's not possible for a function to do as you want and return a string on some inputs and a list of integers on other inputs (as it would be in a dynamic language). But that is what `Either` is for. A value of type `Either a b` is either `Left x` where `x` is a value of type `a`, or `Right y` where `y` is a value of type `b`. Hopefully you can now see why this would be useful for your case.

Comment: `if condition then x else y` requires `x` and `y` to be of the same type. If they are not, say `x :: TypeX` and `y :: TypeY`, you can convert both to `Either TypeX TypeY` as follows: `if condition then Left x else Right y`. Since now the two `if` branches have the same type `Either TypeX TypeY`, it type checks, and that type will be the type of the value resulting from the `if`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I edited the post to reflect my attempt at trying the Either String [a] type and it seems to work!

Comment: And if you really do want to go back to printing the result as a string without the `Left` or `Right`, you can use `div a = putStrLn . either show show $ divisors a` which applies the same function (`show`) to each side of the `Either`, and prints that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*From @RobinZigmond:*  Well you've discovered why you need `Either`. Haskell has a strong static type system, and a function needs to return values of a specific type. It's not possible for a function to do as you want and return a string on some inputs and a list of integers on other inputs (as it would be in a dynamic language). But that is what `Either` is for. A value of type `Either a b` is either `Left x` where `x` is a value of type `a`, or `Right y` where `y` is a value of type `b`. Hopefully you can now see why this would be useful for your case.

*From @chi:* the construct

```
if condition then x else y
```

requires `x` and `y` to be of the same type. If they are not, say:

```
x :: TypeX
y :: TypeY
```

you can convert both to `Either TypeX TypeY` as follows:

```
if condition then Left x else Right y
```

Since now the two `if` branches have the same type `Either TypeX TypeY`, it type checks, and that type will be the type of the value resulting from the `if`.

*From the original poster, @nutbunny:*  After reading some responses, I attempted the following:

```
divisors :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> Either String [a]
divisors a = if length [i | i <- [2..a], mod a i == 0] > 1
             then Right [i | i <- [2..a-1], mod a i == 0]
             else Left (show a ++ " is prime")
```

and it seems to be working!

Thank you for the suggestions!